# How to open and read SQLite files

Tags: text, binary, sqlite

I am trying to recover something from Mozilla Firefox history, and grep returns lots of binary files, I think they come from sqlite content. How can I view them in human-readable form, as text? At the top of the file I see something like
 SQLite format 3

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's any *general* way to turn an arbitrary binary file into human-readable form - you would need to know the byte-by-byte format in order to unpack and convert it. (There is the `strings` utility, but that will only extract ASCII sequences that happen to be embedded in the file).

In the specific case of Mozilla Firefox, it appears to use SQLite 3 - this is likely what you are seeing at the top of the file - this is one time where `strings` *is* useful:

```
$ strings ~/.mozilla/firefox/dhjktlo7.default/storage.sqlite
SQLite format 3
```

although you could also use the `file` command to identify the content type:

```
$ file -b ~/.mozilla/firefox/dhjktlo7.default/storage.sqlite
SQLite 3.x database, user version 65536, last written using SQLite version 3013000
```

Probably the best way to display / search these specific files is to use the `sqlite3` command line client (from package `sqlite3`) to `.dump` them e.g.

```
$ sqlite3 ~/.mozilla/firefox/dhjktlo7.default/storage.sqlite .dump
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Then after you dump everything you can grep if there are multiple files?

Comment: Thanks, any idea on this though https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49889122/searching-through-browser-history

Answer (score 1):

SQLite is a type of relational database, so that file will contain tables, columns and indexes.

[sqlitebrowser](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/sqlitebrowser) is a GUI based application that lets you browse inside SQLite files.

Of course you can simply install [sqlite3](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/sqlite3) itself and use the `sqlite3` command-line tool to open the database.

Comment: Thanks, do you happen to have any idea on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49889122/searching-through-browser-history